# It says Process Finished but there is no output

Tags: java, process

I'm new to java and I'm having a little problem with my code. There's no error and such, it just keeps saying process finished but no output was displayed. The filename is correct as I've checked.

import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

```
public class GuessingGame {
    public GuessingGame() {
        String filename = "C:\\Users\\angela\\Documents\\words.txt";
        Path path = Paths.get(filename.toString());
        
        try {
            InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(path);
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            
            String word = null;
            while((word = read.readLine()) !=null) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new GuessingGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: don't miss out on the exception. Please put a print to confirm if exception has occurred.

Comment: Got it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ignoring the exception and you don't close the file. Save some typing by using the built-in `input.transferTo()` for copying the file to `System.out`, and pass on the exception for the caller to handle by adding `throws IOException` to constructor and `main`.

Replace your try-catch block with this try-with-resources, which handles closing the file after use:

```
try (InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(path)) {
    input.transferTo(System.out) ;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can replace above with one-liner provided by `Files.copy`:

```
Files.copy(path, System.out);
```

Answer (score -1):

You managed to call the intended class, but you also needed to specify the specific function which you have declared in the function. Like so:
`public static void main (String[] args) { GuessingGame gg = new GuessingGame; gg.GuessingGame(); }`

Comment: `new GuessingGame();` is correct as that is the constructor, your suggestion will not compile.

Comment: `gg.GuessingGame()` is not correct. `GuessingGame()` is the constructor, not a method.